# Cocoa ConnectionKit Framework Dependencies

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'd like to use [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionKit) in a project, but haven't yet been able to compile the framework.

I haven't been able to find a definitive list of external projects that ConnectionKit depends on. I've attempted to include projects that fit my best guess, but nothing has worked so far.

Does anyone know exactly what projects / libraries ConnectionKit requires?

Comment: What's going wrong? What errors are you getting? More info is critical to help you figure out what's failing.

Comment: You're right, thank you :) Right now though, I'm asking if anyone knows of a definitive list of dependencies for this framework. Dependencies are alluded to on the project's github page (linked to above), but not listed.

Comment: Judging by the GitHub repository, ConnectionKit seems to already include most if not all of its dependencies. However, it does appear that it relies on two other projects ([SFTP](https://github.com/karelia/libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper) and [DAVKit](https://github.com/karelia/DAVKit)) as submodules (you can download them with `git submodule update --init libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper DAVKit`). The reason I was asking was because any errors would be helpful in determining whether there are even any missing dependencies in the first place, or if anything else is going wrong.

Comment: Ah submodules, this totally slipped my mind! This sounds like a valid solution, if you would put your comment into an answer so when I've tested it and it works, I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take my comment and turn it into an answer: it appears that ConnectionKit already includes many of its dependencies by default. However, there are two Git submodules that you're going to have to install for this framework to compile: "libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper" and "DAVKit".

The easiest way to install them is to `cd` to the framework directory once you've cloned it, and to run `git submodule update --init libssh2_sftp-Cocoa-wrapper DAVKit`.

Comment: Update: there were more submodules present in sub directories. The following command got them all: `git submodule update --init --recursive`. After that I could build it OK.